# Terciles in python (Data analysis in time)

Tags: python, mysql, static, analysis

Regards,
I have drawbacks in generating the following report, I have two fields of time one initial and one final; What is desired is to divide the time into three equal parts (start, intermediate and final).

I was trying to do it with numpy but I do not have enough documentation.

Some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To divide two endpoints into equal segments, use [linspace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.linspace(100, 250, 3)
```

Yields:

```
array([ 100.,  175.,  250.])
```

In general, for N segments you'd need one point for each segment, plus an end cap, for N+1 total points:

```
np.linspace(start, stop, N+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion, I found a combination with numpy and pandas libraries; With your suggestion only probe with numpy and I threw an error for being fields of type datetime and this I could solve with pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

start = pd.Timestamp(start_field)
fin = pd.Timestamp(final_field)
np.linspace(start.value, fin.value, 4) # 4 is the number of divisions.
```

thanks, again.